# How to bind phtml view file with custom view helper

Tags: php, view, zend-framework2

I would like to create custom view helper for a few controls on my page. I decided to use  custom view helper because these controls may be different for different users (logged in and not logged in). However I would like to set layout file for my view instead of just returning html code in __invoke function. Is there a possibility to do that? Or only subviews allow to set phtml view file for them?

Edited (because a lot of confusions which my question made)
This is my view helper invoke function:

```
public function __invoke()
{
    $authService = new AuthenticationService();
    $body = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>";
    if(!$authService->hasIdentity())
    {
        $body .= $this->wrapLi($this->makeUrl($this->view->url('users/default', array('controller' => 'register')),  $this->view->translate('Register')));
        $body .= $this->wrapLi($this->makeUrl($this->view->url('users/default', array('controller' => 'login')),  $this->view->translate('Login')));
    }
    if($authService->hasIdentity())
    {
        $body .= $this->wrapLi($this->makeUrl($this->view->url('users/default', array('controller' => 'logout')),  $this->view->translate('Logout')));
    }
    $body .= "</ul>";
    return $body;
}
```

As you may see it returns just html. 
I use this helper in layout.html this way:

```
<?php echo $this->LoginViewHelper(); ?>
```

I would like to know if there is another way to create html which is returned by invoke function. If there is a possibility to make template.

Comment: I totally don't understand your question. It seems you ask three different things, can you clarify and focus on one problem? Regarding the creation of view helpers, have you read the manual and read how to create a view helper yourself?

Comment: I've already done my own view helper and it returns some html. It is working fine in this moment.
However I was wondering if there is a possibility to create some view for it as it is done for regular views. Instead of returning plain html.

Comment: A view script is a plain text file. You can access view helpers in a view script and even render other view scripts inside a view helper. Is that your question, how to render view scripts inside a view helper?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit lost, the way to load html is with views, that are usually called from a controller, you can recognize them because they have the word action at the end of the method name.

I would recommend you to install the zend framework 2 skeleton, which provide already a module with some views and controller.

But if you want to do something like what you are trying to do now. You could create a new folder called Helper on your Application module, define a namespace like as first line:

```
namespace Application\Helper;
```

then create a static method:

```
class H {
    public static function LoginViewHelper(){

    }
}
```

on your view call it like this

```
<?php echo \Application\Helper\H::LoginViewHelper() ?>
```